# If limit of $ \lim_{x\to0}(\frac{sin2x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2} + b) $ is zero, then find a+b?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If limit is zero:
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2} + b\right) = 0 $$

then find $ a+b=? $

please help me to solve this question, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean if limit is zero then find  $a+b $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Taylor's expansion shows:
$$\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2} + b=\frac{a+2}{x^2}+\left(b-\frac{4}{3}\right)+\frac{4 x^2}{15}-\frac{8 x^4}{315}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Therefore $a=-2$ and $b=\frac43$.

---

Some explanations:

define $f(x)=x^2(\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2} + b)=\frac{\sin 2x}{x} + a + bx^2$. Now recall $\sin x =x-\frac16x^3+\frac{1}{120}x^5+O(x^6)$. Therefore $$f(x)=a+bx^2+2-\frac{4}{3}x^2+\frac{4}{15}x^4+O(x^6)$$hence $$\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2} + b=\frac{a+bx^2+2-\frac{4}{3}x^2+\frac{4}{15}x^4+O(x^6)}{x^2}=\frac{a+2}{x^2}+(b-\frac43)+\frac{4}{15}x^2+O(x^4)$$

Now if you want the limit at zero to be zero you must have $a=-2$ so that the first term is zero and then $b=\frac34$. the rest of the terms in the expansion are zero at zero, since they are a multiple of $x$.

Comment: your answer is correct, but please explain it, thanks.

Comment: sure, see the explanations :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solution Using **L'Hospital's** Rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} + \frac{a}{x^2} + b\right) = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{sin(2x)+ax+bx^3}{x^3}\right)= 
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{2cos(2x)+a+3bx^2}{3x^2}\right) $$

But We're given that the limit exists and is equal to zero hence we must have $a+2=0$ i.e.$ a=-2$.

Now as $a=-2$ therefore the following limit is zero  $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3} - \frac{2}{x^2} + b\right)$$.

Applying the same technique as above we get $b=4/3$.

Comment: thanks, I think L'Hospital's Rule is better and similar than another rule for solving this question.

Answer (score 0):

As $\sin y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2r+1}(-1)^r}{(2r+1)!},$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin2x}{x^3}+\dfrac a{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2x-\dfrac43x^3+O(x^5)+ax}{x^3}=\dfrac{a+2}{x^2}-\dfrac43$$

For the existence of the limit, $a+2$ must be zero

Comment: The equation $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \cdots \right) = (a+2)/x^2-4/3$ is very disturbing...

Comment: @user37238, Just set $a+2=0$ get a nice form:)